# How can I limit python script to 1 API trade per day?

Tags: python, json, api, cryptocurrency, poloniex

I'm putting together a python script to make trades on poloniex with the API, and so far I've got it to make trades when certain conditions are met, but I still need it to NOT place anymore trades for the rest of that day (I have the entire script looping every 60 seconds).

So far I have this script:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import http.client
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

The_Currency_Pair = input('Which Currency Pair?\nPAIRS TO CHOOSE FROM:\nUSDT_BTC\nUSDT_XRP\nUSDT_ETH\nUSDT_BCH\nUSDT_STR\nUSDT_LTC\nUSDT_ETC\nUSDT_XMR\n')


api = 'https://poloniex.com/tradingApi'
key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'


def main():
    poloniexPrices = urlopen('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker').read()
    poloniexjson = json.loads(poloniexPrices)
    poloniexlastP = poloniexjson[The_Currency_Pair]['last']


    poloniexOCHL = urlopen('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=USDT_BCH&start=1538352000&period=86400').read()
    poloniexOCHLjson = json.loads(poloniexOCHL)
    poloniexlasthigh = poloniexOCHLjson[-2]['high']


    print ('Last Price')
    print (poloniexlastP)
    print ('----------------------------------------')
    print ('Last Day High')
    print (poloniexlasthigh)
    print ('----------------------------------------')



    data = {
        'command': 'returnBalances',
        'nonce'  : int(time.time() * 1000)
    }
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode()

    signature = hmac.new(secret.encode(), data, hashlib.sha512)

    headers = {
        'Key' : key,
        'Sign': signature.hexdigest()
    }

    request = urllib.request.Request(
        url=api, data=data, headers=headers, method='POST'
    )

    text = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read().decode()

    print ('MY ACCOUNT BALANCE')
    try:
        print(json.loads(text)['USDT'])
    except:
        print(text)
    print ('-----------------------------------------')



    if float(poloniexlastP) > 0:
        print ('PLACING TRADE')
        print ('-----------------------------------------------')

        parms = {"command":"buy",
             "currencyPair":The_Currency_Pair,
             "rate":100,
             "immediateOrCancel":1,
             "amount":0.01,
             "nonce":int(time.time() * 1000)}

        parms = urllib.parse.urlencode(parms).encode()

        signature = hmac.new(secret.encode(), parms, hashlib.sha512)

        headers = {'Key' : key,
                   'Sign': signature.hexdigest()}

        request = urllib.request.Request(
        url=api, data=parms, headers=headers, method='POST')

        text = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read().decode()

        ordernumber = (json.loads(text)['orderNumber'])

        print ('Order Number:')
        print (ordernumber)




while True:
    main()
    time.sleep(60)
```

Anyway, after a trade has been placed, I need it to make sure that after the 60 second sleep, it doesn't make a second trade unless it is a new day/the day after the trade was made. (Could I use poloniex server time for this?)

So, if it has got as far as `print (ordernumber)` that means it has placed a trade. But how do I mark it as placed trade for the day or something and use it in the `if float(poloniexlastP) > 0:` for the next loop to make sure it doesn't place another one?

Comment: Where is `main()`?  This code does not work.  Please generate an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: main() is further up the code. I've only provided the part of code that I need help with.

Comment: Please read the link I provided.  Super important.  Thanks.

Comment: I have edited and included the full script.

Comment: And naturally, I have replaced my api key and secret with multiple Xs.

Comment: One important point of MCVE is the M (Minimal).  Dumping the world is just muddying the waters and forcing those who might be willing to help to do work that you could have done yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use Python to get the date, and create a global variable,  and after the `print` statement, you can set the variable to the current date, and the coffee will check if it has already sent, that way it doesn't execute more than once in a day.

```
import datetime
# This Gets The Day Of The Month
todaysDateNumber = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d"))
dateNumberTradeSent = 0
if todaysDateNumber == dateNumberTradeSent:
    print("The API has already been used once today, try again tomorrow!")
    return
else:
    # Call Your Trade Sending Code Here
    # After The Print Statement That Shows That The Trade Was Sent:
    global dateNumberTradeSent
    dateNumberTradeSent = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d"))
```

Comment: Perhaps, but is there a way to use poloniex server time instead? Because that's the time I need it to go by. I don't want it to place a second trade until it reaches exactly midnight poloniex server time. This may provide what would be needed: https://poloniex.com/support/api/#rest_public

Comment: To make things more easy to understand, I've updated the question with the full script.